# Json object rearrange divs via css left

Tags: jquery, json

I am recieving a json object, but i am having trouble rearrange my divs in a  tag.  where i have a list of divs that are movable and once move you can save the order.  My issue is that on loading my page i can not seem to rearrange my divs?  (val.divname is the divs id and val.left is the left position extracted from my json)

```
 $.getJSON("http://test.com/test", function( json) {
  $.each( json, function( key, val ) {    

 $("#" + val.divname).css({left:" + val.left + "px"}); 
 });   
}
```

Comment: `$("#" + val.divname).css({left: val.left});` is enough

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error

Comment: "I am recieving a json object, but i am having trouble rearrange my divs in a tag." - These two actions are not related. In the future, you may find it easier to find a solution by first breaking problems down. In this case, "Am I successfully making an AJAX request and getting a response?", and "Can I change the left styling of my divs?"

Answer (score 0):

your quotes ordering is wrong.

Do like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://test.com/test", function( json) {
  $.each( json, function( key, val ) {    

 $("#" + val.divname).css("left:" + val.left+ "px"); 
 });   
}
```

Comment: TY Ehsan, but my div's are still in their default ordwer and have not moved.  I have checked and I am 100% recieving data back, but its just not ordering my divs positions correctly?

Comment: Also Im not sure if this makes any difference, but my divs i am trying to rearrange are within two other container divs.  The divs all have the same class and float left.  There is no CSS for the Div ID either.

Comment: paste the html after the json response, may be your css is written in a way due to which left property is not working